# Слитно или с дефисом

Tags: орфография

Микробизнес, инфопакет, слитно или с дефисом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Микро  и инфо -  первые части сложносокращённых слов, пишутся слитно.  "Микро" в переводе с греческого означает "малый", "маленький".

Микробизнес- малый бизнес, инфопакет - информационный пакет, образованы от подчинительных сочетаний.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Инфопакет*** – сложносокращенное слово.

Вопрос № 281384

Подскажите, как пишется "инфо-стенд" или "инфостенд"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**Сложносокращенные** слова пишутся слитно: инфостенд.

2. ***Микробизнес*** – **СЛОЖНОЕ** слово.

Из словаря: **МИКРО**... [от греч. mikrós - малый] Первая часть **сложных слов**. 1. Вносит зн.: очень малый, мелкий. Микроавтобус, микроавтомобиль, микроиздание, микроновелла, микроорганизм, микросистема, микрофотокопия.

Или всё-таки **СЛОЖНОСОКРАЩЕННОЕ**? Теперь уж я сомневаюсь.  Тогда получается: микроскоп – микроскопический бизнес – микробизнес?

**МИКРОСКОПИЧЕСКИЙ**,  1. Производимый с помощью микроскопа.2. Очень малый, видимый только в микроскоп.  3. Разг. Чрезмерно маленький, ничтожный по размерам, величине.  4. Разг. Подробнейший, детальный, скрупулёзный (о разборе, анализе и т.п.).  5. Разг. Крайне незначительный, мелкий, не имеющий почти никакого значения.

**Вроде бы ничего не подходит, ну да ладно.** Кому это все интересно! Главное – пишется слитно.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (улучшаем свой ответ)

**Как пишется слово?**  Можно посмотреть в словаре на Грамоте.ру, если больше ничего интересует.

**Почему оно так пишется?** Можно  дать свой ответ,  основанный на имеющихся знаниях, если автора вопроса это устраивает. Можно (и даже желательно)  **сослаться на правила**  или хотя бы на ответ справочной службы .

Эти правила лучше изложено в ПАС. https://orfhographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=65#pp65
https://orfhographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=64#pp64

**МИКРОБИЗНЕС**

§ 117. Следующие разряды слов пишутся слитно.

3. Сложные слова с первой иноязычной (интернациональной) частью, кончающейся на гласную. Перечень основных таких частей сложных слов:
   с конечным о: авто-, агро-, астро-, аудио-, аэро-, баро-, бензо-, био-, вело-, вибро-, видео-, гекто-, гелио-, гео-, гетеро-, гидро-, гомо-, дендро-, зоо-, изо-, кило-, кино-, космо-, **макро**-, метео-, **микро**-, моно-, мото-, невро-, нейро-, нео-, орто-, палео-, пиро-, пневмо-, порно-, психо-, радио-, ретро-, сейсмо-, социо-, спектро-, стерео-, термо-, турбо-, фито-, фоно-, фото-, эвако-, экзо-, эко-, электро-, эндо-, энерго-;

Но:  **МИНИ-КОМПЬЮТЕР**. Почему?

§ 120. Следующие разряды существительных и сочетания существительных пишутся через дефис:

п.4.  Слова с первыми частями диско- (муз.), **макси**-, миди-, **мини**- (как **ОТСТУПЛЕНИЕ** от правила § 117, п. 3), напр.: диско-клуб, диско-музыка, макси-мода, миди-юбка, мини-платье, мини-трактор, мини-футбол, мини-ЭВМ.

**ИНФОПАКЕТ**

§ 119. Следующие разряды существительных пишутся слитно.

2. **Сложносокращенные** слова, напр.: артобстрел, военврач, госторговля, загранпаспорт, запчасти, **киберпространство**, компартия, машбюро, натуроплата, пединститут, политэмигрант, соцреализм, спецвыпуск, спецПТУ, стенгазета, танцплощадка, трансагентство, хозтовары; колхоз, профорг, комсомол, торгпредство, эсминец.